# Lua function that replaces strings, but ignores spaces and TeX comments

Tags: luatex, strings, lua

I would like a Lua function for LuaTeX, called

```
replaceButIgnoreSpacesAndComments (<string>, <what to replace>, <what to replace it by>)
```

It is supposed to work like a string replacement function, except that when scanning the `<string>`,
it must ignore all whitespace and TeX comments. It should preferably not *remove* comments and whitespace in general, though, outside the text it replaces.

In other words, I want `replaceButIgnoreSpacesAndComments` to work approximately like this: If I run

```
replaceButIgnoreSpacesAndComments( [[
    \mymacro
    [
        3 % this is my comment
    ]
    {
        4 % this is my argument
    } + b + c % another comment
]] , "\mymacro[3]{4}", "\frac{x+3}{x+4}")
```

then this should return the string

```
[[
    \frac{x+3}{x+4} + b + c % another comment
]]
```

A TeX command `\ReplaceButIgnoreSpacesAndComments` would also have been fine, but I cannot see how one would get this to preserve comments.

I would also like a variant, `replaceOnceButIgnoreSpacesAndComments`, which is supposed to works a bit like `\tl_replace_once:Nnn`, i.e. it should only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Your objective in removing (or ignoring) whitespace as part of the string manipulation function you seek to create isn't clear to me. TeX ignores whitespace while in math mode. Hence, why bother removing whitespace in a string before turning it over to TeX for final processing?

Comment: @Mico If I just use a Lua replacement function on that example, Lua will not find the string because it contains whitespace and comments. What I am building is essentially a de-macro system for a package of mine, so it should preferably not remove other comments or spaces outside the string it replaces.

Comment: This make absolutely no sense.  Why do you want to retain arbitrary comments but not others?  There is also no way to perform this kind of thing in a robust way using Lua string replacement, because it doesn't know about tokens or macro expansion.  Maybe you could use the `token` library but that is probably more work than you are willing to invest.

Comment: @HenriMenke As I wrote above, it is for a de-macro system for a package of mine. It’s supposed to remove specific macros from your document and replace them with raw code. You don’t want to remove arbitrary comments, just those that were in the way when you did the replacement. In any case, I think I have figured out a more robust approach to doing it in my specific case.